# parse float value 1000000.1 into String in java

Tags: java, floating-point

In my web application I have a version field that take float input values. But when using values like 1000000.1 (or larger) for the version it displays like 1.0E7. i tried several methods in Float wrapper class. but result still the same.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is not in parsing but in formatting of your values. The value is correct and it is represented in java correctly. If you wish to change the format user either String.format() that provides C style formatting or java.text.NumberFormat.

Answer (score 1):

`System.out.printf("%f", Float.parseFloat("1.0E7"));` outputs `10000000.000000`

See http://ideone.com/3o6dO

Note that 1.0E7 is 1000000.0, *not* 1000000.1.

Answer (score 0):

it probably has to do with your output format because 1.0E7 == 10000000

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is the [`String.format(locale, msg, args)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.util.Locale%2C%20java.lang.String%2C%20java.lang.Object...%29) method.

Answer (score -1):

Use `String.valueOf(floatNumber)`
Suggest use double instead of float